# How to encode from JSON to binary Protobuf on command line?

Tags: json, serialization, command-line, protocol-buffers, protoc

How to serialize JSON to binary Protocol Buffers (Protobuf) serialization on command line? Assuming the JSON follows [Protobuf 3 JSON Mapping](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json))

Question [How to encode protocol buffer string to binary using protoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087310/how-to-encode-protocol-buffer-string-to-binary-using-protoc) has an answer for serializing to Protobuf binary from [Protobuf Text Format Language](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/textformat-spec/) with `protoc --decode` but if I have understood right, `protoc` doesn't support JSON. With that, converting from JSON to Protobuf Text Format should answer the need.

Comment: It isn't supported by protoc. However, if you are willing to write some python (or whatever language) this is feasible. Let me know the language you would prefer and I can post an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the offer!

I roughly have that already for my current need, though it would be nice to find a way with minimal tooling.

Comment: I would say that a binary containing all dependencies would be similar to protoc (you can maybe even wrap protoc commands). You can do that with Go for example.